# How can I revert back the native javascript code coloring in Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

I recently installed Adobe Dreamweaver CS4. When I tried to code in javascript, all my code is written in pink font. I checked my Preferences > Code Coloring  then choose Javascript. I was surprised to see that it only recognizes 3 types of code: jQuery Identifiers, jQuery Keywords and Methods, jQuery objects. I do code jQuery, but I want to see the previous color coding from my pass Installation (Macromedia Dreamweaver version XX). What can I do to revert or add these native code types so I can set their syntax color. I'm just used to seeing these codes more color-coded. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask because I have the following options when I open up the JavaScript code coloring options:

- JavaScript Bracket
- JavaScript Client Keywords
- JavaScript Comment
- JavaScript Default Text
- JavaScript Function Keyword
- JavaScript Identifier
- JavaScript Native Keywords
- JavaScript Number
- JavaScript Operator
- JavaScript RegExp
- JavaScript Reserved Keywords
- JavaScript String

I just checked in CS4 and CS5 and those entries are present in both, there are no entries for jQuery. Have you installed an extension that provides jQuery support (at least code coloring)?  If you have, then I'd suggest you uninstalling it and the modifications may be reverted.

If you have uninstalled the extension, or if you don't have an extension installed, and the code coloring is still awry, to get back to the original code coloring that's built into Dreamweaver, you may need to perform step 12 on this page:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/191/tn_19105.html

For CS4 and CS5, the folder to remove will have a "language" folder that the Configuration folder is within. On my Vista system for CS5, it's at:
C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5\en_US\configuration\

Comment: What I did is I installed my old Macromedia Dreamweaver 8. Then I copied the old "MapColoring" or something folder to the existing Dreamweaver CS4 directory of the same name. That fixed it! :D Thanks for the answer, though.